# Add a tag using HtmlGenericControl

Tags: c#, onclick, htmlgenericcontrol

I want to add 'a' tag with onserverclick attribute

I'm using the following code.But onserverclick event not firing(Not working)

onserverclick:

```
protected void Pagination_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

My C# Code:

```
HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
olpage.Controls.Add(li);


HtmlGenericControl a = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
a.Attributes.Add("ID", i.ToString());
a.Attributes.Add("onserverclick", "Pagination_Click");
a.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
li.Controls.Add(a);
```

HTML Code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"CodeFile="Products.master.cs" Inherits="Productmaster"%>...
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">...
    <div class="pages">
         <ol id="olpage" runat="server">

         </ol>
    </div>...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your C# code to use a LinkButton instead of a HTMLGenericControl and instead of setting an attribute of onserverclick set it with Click +=

```
LinkButton a = new LinkButton();
a.Attributes.Add("ID", i.ToString()); 
a.Click += Pagination_Click;
a.Text = i.ToString();
li.Controls.Add(a);
```

The HTMLGenericControl just renders as

```
<a id="id" onserverclick="Pagination_Click">id</a>
```

And the browser doesn't know what to do with the onserverclick attribute as it's not valid HTML. Using the LinkButton renders as

```
<a id="id" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$ctl01','')">id</a>
```

Which actually causes it to post back